# set private name server on Hetzner cloud

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, hetzner

Default robots dns info is this and it works:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    201208   ; serial
    86400        ; refresh
    10800        ; retry
    3600000      ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       95.111.1.11
mail                     IN A       95.111.1.11
www                      IN A       95.111.1.11
```

So for private nameserver, first I registered these two names server in 'Registered nameservers' section:

```
dns1.example.com  IP:95.111.1.11
dns2.example.com  IP:95.111.1.11
```

And then I try to add them to the DNS code:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    201208   ; serial
    86400        ; refresh
    10800        ; retry
    3600000      ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      dns1.example.com.
@                        IN NS      dns2.example.com.

@                        IN A       95.111.1.11
mail                     IN A       95.111.1.11
www                      IN A       95.111.1.11
```

But not works.

what is my wrong?

Comment: Are both `dns1.example.com.` and `dns2.example.com.` actually sharing the same IP address?

Comment: @EsaJokinen yes

Answer (score 0):

There are IANA [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements), and your single DNS server configuration doesn't meet these requirements:

> **Minimum number of name servers**
>
> There must be at least two NS records listed in a delegation, and the
>   hosts must not resolve to the same IP address.
>
> **Valid hostnames**
>
> The hostnames used for the name servers must comply with the
>   requirements for valid hostnames described in RFC 1123, section 2.1.
>
> **Network diversity**
>
> The name servers must be in at least two topologically separate
>   networks. A network is defined as an origin autonomous system in the
>   BGP routing table. The requirement is assessed through inspection of
>   views of the BGP routing table.

You need at least one secondary authoritative name server. Luckily, [Hetzner provides a slave DNS](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/DNS_Robot/en#Option_.22Slave_DNS_entry.22) server. Then, if this is the zone for the same `example.com` domain, it must have a corresponding `A` record for the `dns1.example.com` and it must match the *glue record* at the parent zone.